# Clutch is soft after car sat for 2 weeks

Tags: clutch, bmw, clutch-cylinder, bleeding

I have a 2002 E39 BMW. I went for a 2 week vacation. After coming home, I found the clutch of the car to be completly soft, and a medium size oil (or more likely, brake fluid) leak under the car. I am guessing that the slave cylinder went bad. I have to get the car to the mechanic which is on the other side of the city.

What are my options? Could I bleed the clucth at home and fill it up with brake fluid so I can drive the car to the mechanic?

If yes, could someone give me some info on how to do this on an E39.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of ways to bleed a clutch. One is to "gravity" bleed it, another is to bleed it much as you would a brake system, having someone pump the pedal, then hold it to the floor and open the bleeder valve to let the air out, close and do it again until there is only fluid coming out. But it sounds like the fluid drained completely out of your master cylinder. In that case the lack of fluid means air is probably in the master, making it difficult to get it to "pump up". 
The alternative is to fill the master with fluid, open the bleeder valve on the slave cylinder, have someone push the clutch pedal down to the floor ONE TIME. When it is on the floor, close the bleeder. Have them let the pedal up and do it again, and again, etc until you get solid fluid from the bleeder. Don't forget to check the fluid during the process so you don't run out and cause the same issue again. Good luck!